# Async task progress dialog not showing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am having trouble with displaying the progress dialog spinner. I have looked at several threads and the proposed solutions do not seem to work.

All of the code in this `AsyncTask` does get called successfully however I cannot see the progress spinner being displayed. This `AsycTask` is defined in a separate class and it is being called from my fragment where I pass `getActivity()` as the context.

My thought is that the issue is related to how the context is being given to the progress dialog.

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    private class loginAsyncTest  extends AsyncTask<HttpPackage, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        Context spinnerContext;

        public void setSpinnerContext(Context context)
        {
            spinnerContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(spinnerContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
            Log.d("http", "dialog spinner started");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(HttpPackage... httpParameters)
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = httpParameters[0].getUrl();
            // Get HTTP parameters that are passed in
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameterList = httpParameters[0].getParameters();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            String responseJson = "";

            try
            {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameterList));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    responseJson = responseJson + line;
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return responseJson;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            if(dialog.isShowing())
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the call to ExampleClass that comes from a fragment which provides the context.

```
Public class SampelFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_login, container, false);    

        ExampleClass.loginRequest(params, getActivity()));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

ExampleClass then passes the context onto our `AsyncTask`

```
public String loginRequest(HttpPackage postParameters, Context context)    
{
    loginAsyncTest loginAsync = new loginAsyncTest(context);
    loginAsync.execute(postParameters);

    return someString;
}
```

Comment: where you are executing?

Comment: @Lakhan I am calling the async task from the fragment I would like the progress dialog to be displayed in, however the async task resides in a separate class where it can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ExampleClass.this` as the given Context and make sure you're calling the method setSpinnerContext().

Also, I think that it would be better if instead the method `setSpinnerContext()` you add a constructor for `loginAsyncTask` that receives the Context. So I would replace the method `setSpinnerContext(Context context)` with this:

```
public loginAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
```

and you should instantiate it as
`new loginAsyncTask(ExampleClass.this).execute();`

Comment: Thank you, however ExampleClass is a basic utility class, which from my understanding does not have a context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you have ever called publishProgress() or overridden onProgressUpdate(). In my apps, I call publishProgress() in my doInBackground() method, which consequently updates my progress bar. The [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the Android docs is super simple but very helpful:

You might also consider creating the progress bar outside of the AsyncTask and passing it to the AsynchTask as a parameter in the constructor or via a setter method. That way you don't have to wonder if the correct context is being used.

Comment: No need for that, a progress dialog will just work fine with what the OP is doing. There seem to be some minor issue, I think joaquin's solution will fix it.